# Get selected cell indexPath.section and indexPath.row in button action in swift

Tags: ios, swift

i'm having a table view in my view controller, in which there are some sections and cells under that sections. These sections and cells are dynamic. i have a button with an action attached to it. I want to get the indexPath.section and indexPath.row of that selected cell in my button action where i'm making a condition on the basis of that. How can i get that in my button action? 
My code for selecting cell is,

```
if allowedSelection == 0 {

            if selectionStatus == false {

                let sectionToReload = indexPath.section

                let indexSet: IndexSet = [sectionToReload]

                selection[indexPath.section].isSelected[indexPath.row] = !selectionStatus

                let price = AddonCategoryModel![indexPath.section].addonItems![indexPath.row].price

                selection[indexPath.section].numberOfSelectedItems = selection[indexPath.section].numberOfSelectedItems - 1


                selection[indexPath.section].sectionRowsPrice[indexPath.row] = price!

                self.addonTableView.reloadSections(indexSet, with: .automatic)


            }
```

Here is my button action in which i want to get both of them,

```
if selctedItems == allowedSelection{

        var addOnItemsSum = 0

        for index in 0..<selection.count {

            for count in 0..<selection[index].sectionRowsPrice.count {

                addOnItemsSum = addOnItemsSum + selection[index].sectionRowsPrice[count]
                print(addOnItemsSum)
            }

        }
else
{
print("Hello")
}
```

Yet it is only giving me results on index 0 i want it to give of the selected index.My button is outside the table view like a normal button having an action.

Comment: Please add the relevant part. this has nothing to do with getting the indexpath on button action

Comment: Please provide more details about what you want to achieve. I have a feeling that you are trying to do something completely irrelevant with you actual objectives.

Comment: i want that , i have a button in my vc in that button action i want to get the indexPath.section and indexPath.row in my button action. How can i get that. @SahilManchanda

Comment: i want to get the indexPath.section and indexPath.row in my button action. @MichaelV

Comment: You have that button in tableview cell or outside of tableview

Comment: Its outside the table view. @SahilManchanda

Comment: No its not duplicate the reference you give is the button inside the cell but in mine case the button is outside the tableview.@SahilManchanda

Comment: i know that's why i removed it

Comment: So how can u get that in my action? @SahilManchanda

Comment: create an extension of your class and confirm it to protocol UITableViewDelegate. there you will get the method didSelectRow at whenever any row is selected this method will get called. from there you can maintain an array of selected cells

Comment: and on your button action simple iterate through your array

Comment: There are multiple conditions in my didselect method of tableview, like for section 0  there is some condition and for section 1 there is another condition.@SahilManchanda

Comment: @raheem why not use with tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows then?